# Docco ignore blocks of comments

Tags: coffeescript, docco

I am using docco as a tool for creating coffeescript documentation.

By default, every comment I make in coffeescript source is treated as documentation and moved to the left (explainatory) column.
The problem is, in my source there are some lines of code commented out, left as alternate options, which I want to remain in the right (code) column.

Is there a way to tell docco- "do not touch that, leave this like it is a normal code"?
"#!" or "#ignore" maybe?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it?  It will ignore `#!` hashbang lines.

> Ignore [hashbangs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and interpolations...

```
        l.commentFilter = /(^#![/]|^\s*#\{)/
      languages
    languages = buildMatchers languages
```

From the source, line 277  https://github.com/jashkenas/docco/blob/master/docco.litcoffee

If nothing else, you should be able to edit the source to add whatever opt out you would like there.

Comment: To be honest- yes. But I'll try again; maybe I haven't noticed it working ("#!"-idea was just blind-guessed).

Edit: Yes, it does not work. Should I pass any parameter to docco?

Comment: strange.  If you look at line 277 of the source you can see it tries to ignore those https://github.com/jashkenas/docco/blob/master/docco.litcoffee

Comment: as the code above impies,using `#{ ignored by docco` works for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, lab419; 
#{ makes it behave as I'd like it to do